# Scala: Sending/processing typed messages to/with Actors

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a Scala Actor that has an Option pipeline. I want to be able to send Option messages to this actor, which will then go on to invoke the option pipeline and do something with the result. If something like this exists already do you know where I can find it?

Please find my code below along with the strange compile error i'm getting:

"The SBT builder crashed while compiling your project. This is a bug in the Scala compiler or SBT. Check the Erorr Log for details. The error message is: null"

MonadChainActor.scala

```
import scala.actors.Actor

class MonadChainActor[T](monadChain: Option[T]=>Option[T]) extends Actor {

  case class OptionMessage(o:Option[T])

  def act() {
    while(true){
      receive {
        case OptionMessage(o) => println(monadChain(o).get)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Main.scala

```
def monadIntChain(a:Option[Int]):Option[Int] = 
  a.map(x => x+1).map(x => x+1).map(x => x+1)

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var a = new MonadChainActor(monadIntChain)
    a ! a.OptionMessage(Some(1))  
  }
}
```

Comment: Haha, I like that one: `The error message is: null`. Seriously, you should report this to the Scala bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you found a bug in the scala compiler. I noticed that if you don't use the path-dependent type `OptionMessage`, it works (I've also added a `Stop` message):

```
import scala.actors.Actor

class MonadChainActor[T](monadChain: Option[T]=>Option[T]) extends Actor {
  case object Stop
  def act() {
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case o: Option[T] => println(monadChain(o).get)
        case Stop => exit()
      }
    }
  }
}

object Main {
  def monadIntChain(a:Option[Int]):Option[Int] = 
    a.map(x => x+1).map(x => x+1).map(x => x+1)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var a = new MonadChainActor(monadIntChain)
    a.start
    a ! Some(3)  
    a ! a.Stop
  }
}
```

Or you can declare it outside the actor (I declared `Stop` outside just to be consistent):

```
import scala.actors.Actor

case class OptionMessage[T](o:Option[T])
case object Stop

class MonadChainActor[T](monadChain: Option[T]=>Option[T]) extends Actor {
  def act() {
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case om : OptionMessage[T] => println(monadChain(om.o).get)
        case Stop => exit()
      }
    }
  }
}

object Main {
  def monadIntChain(a:Option[Int]):Option[Int] = 
    a.map(x => x+1).map(x => x+1).map(x => x+1)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var a = new MonadChainActor(monadIntChain)
    a.start
    a ! OptionMessage(Some(3))  
    a ! Stop
  }
}
```